# A Real Estate Website Using Drupal

Tags: 7

My friend wants me to create a Real Estate Search Engine for him where Users can submit Real Estate Information so that others can view them ( by searching or any other method ).

I want to use Drupal because I have worked with it earlier. If there is a plugin/add-on for Drupal which can help me make a Real Estate Website, please do include a link in your answer to the plugin or module page(The Plugin or module should be free of cost).

Is there any other CMS which I can use ( Real Estate Plugin should be available )? or should I go with Drupal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal, you will not find a specific "Real Estate Module". (Well, there is [one](http://drupal.org/project/home), but it's a dev version for Drupal 5 and there's only 1 site using it :-)) Drupal modules tend to be more abstract: you take a module for building list pages, add a module for image handling, use a third module for send-to-a-friend functionality, etc. etc. The great thing about Drupal is that 99.9% of the time, you don't have to worry if those modules are compatible with each other. They just build on core concepts such as nodes, fields, menu's and users.

That said, I think you should be able to build a real estate site by combining the modules you need. This way, you will end up with a much more flexible system than a monolithic real estate plugin can ever offer.

I can't be really specific about which modules you need, because I don't know your exact requirements. For the basic functionality you don't even need additional modules; [Drupal 7 core](http://drupal.org/project/drupal) allows you to set up a content type (let's call it 'property'), add fields to the *property* content type (like an image field, price field, address field) and adjust permissions so logged in users (or anonymous, if you want) can create *property* nodes. Drupal core also includes basic search functionality.

After that, add contributed modules if needed:

- [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create all kinds of lists (plain, with filters, sortable tables, etc.)
- [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to create nice search engine optimized URLs
- things like [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location), [Gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) and/or [Locationmap](http://drupal.org/project/locationmap) (I haven't tried them yet in D7) for maps and geolocations

I recommend that you start building a basic site first and ask more specific questions when you run into them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you please tell me which plugins I can use?

Comment: I updated my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [dRealty IDX](http://drupal.org/project/drealty) for D7:

> dRealty is a Real Estate Module to import Listings into drupal via the
>   RETS protocol. It aims to become a full fledged IDX solution for
>   Drupal.
>
> dReatly IDX offers the following functionality:
>
> - Provides an interface to define multiple RETS service connections.
> - Provides an interface to Setup a MLS feed, allowing a user to import real estate listings into the Drupal system.
> - The module leverages the power of Entities, they are field-able!
> - Users have the ability to update and flush their MLS feeds
> - Integration with CTools to provide Importing and Exporting of connections
> - drush integration.
> - works wonderfully with search api

Answer (score 0):

There is [rListing - Real Estate Listing](http://drupal.org/project/rlisting)

Module can be found here https://github.com/vzeazy/rlisting

Looks like its paid now .. http://rlisting.com/

Give it a try..