# Should we use Drupal Commerce for a real estate site?

Tags: 7, commerce

we are about to build a real estate website for a property agency. The site allows visitors to look for apartment for rent/sale.

Property search is actually the first main functionality. Users can search real estate with its attributes such as: price, land area, building area, number of room, facilities, etc. Second main functionality is they can also filter the property list (search result), sort or paginate it.

The visitors can make a contact too, just a simple form with anonymous user information and an ID of real_estate content type maybe. Users don't have to login to contact.

The following features is not needed: User authentication, Checkout Progress, Payment, Cart, Order, Comment, Discount, Shipping, Taxing.

**We wonder if we can use Drupal Commerce to get quickly some out-of-the-box features (advanced search, filterable/sortable list) or it's better to build things from scratch.**

PS: We've found "[A Real Estate Website Using Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14057)" but we still wonder if the [Drupal RETS Real Estate Framework (dRealty)](http://drupal.org/project/drealty) module can fulfill our requirements and if the first answer is still consistent as it has 6 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go from scratch, it's so easy to to make the advanced search and filter/sortable lists .. commerce without distribution needs the same work anyway .. if you go with kickstart, you'll will have a massive overhead.

> dRealty seems very active and up to date for me - i would give this a
>   try !

I found this real estate distribution, maybe check it out -- there's not much information about it .. https://www.drupal.org/project/property

Comment: Hi, after trying both Drupal Commerce and dRealty, we finally decided to go from scratch. Thank @Pierre.Vriens and rémy. The Commerce module is so well constructed that we just need about 10%~20% of what it provides. And a massive overhead to get into it is a real thing to think about. Thank rémy for noticing me. However, dRealty would be ready to run only if you are located in the North America as our client (based at Japan) seems to hear it the first time. It's well built too with functions related to a unified real estate DB.  Anyway, dRealty actually gave us some ideas too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely consider [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) or [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) for this, because it seems to have everything you're looking for.

About the facilities you don't need, like "*Checkout, Payment, Discount, Shipping, Taxing, etc*": that's a matter of NOT enabling the corresponding modules you get with it.